# How to query --log-opt settings on a running container or service?

Tags: docker

I've used `docker service update my_service --log-opt mode=non-blocking` to change the logging options on a running service.

However, is there a way to then query the service (or its containers) to find out what `--log-opt` options are active?

`docker service inspect` or `docker container inspect` don't seem to have this information.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`docker inspect <container_name_or_id>` should return some JSON, with the log configuration in `HostConfig` ==> `LogConfig`.

For example:

```
## Run an example container with some log options:

$ docker run --rm -d --log-opt mode=non-blocking  --name my_running_container alpine:3.9 sleep 600
a54704cb9a0929797d0b66b9dd93d8c792fb2199ce9ad041880f45ebd2d36cba

## Use "docker inspect" to see the container's config, and "jq" to filter the JSON:

$ docker inspect my_running_container | jq '.[0].HostConfig.LogConfig'
{
  "Type": "json-file",
  "Config": {
    "mode": "non-blocking"
  }
}
```

Comment: Great, thanks!  Sorry I hadn't spotted that in the `docker container inspect` output.  Any ideas why a) this info isn't shown in the `docker service inspect` output and b) why the containers don't seem to honour the values you set on the service that manages them?  Maybe you can't actually set this stuff via `docker service update` despite what the docs say?

Comment: Ah, I think [this](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/31515#issuecomment-321011661) may answer my question: sounds like you have to specify `--log-driver json-file` on the service too, otherwise it ignores your `--log-opts`!  Would have been nice if they mentioned that in the docs...